# Nested While Loop with Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested

I want to build a table like the following with Python.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 6 7 8 9 10 11
6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

The code is like this

```
i = 0
j = 0
total = 6

while j <= total:
    while i <= total:
        print(i, "\t", end="")
        i += 1
        print("")
    j += 1
```

I got an error "unindent does not match any outer indentation level", which says "j += 1" was wrong. I use Sublime Text 3 as my IDE. Please tell me what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: The indentation might be an issue related to your text editor. ITworked with my PC. 
However, your loop is wrong, you won't get the exepected result. In addition, your code is not pythonic at all. You should consider using a single loop for... in range(x, y) instead.

Comment: when you figure out your  indentation you might try  printing i and j in the second print, you might see something interesting

Comment: Could you correct my loop with "while way"? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Which IDE are you using? Recall that Python is sensitive to spacing and recall that the "indents" are not actually Tabs, they are EXACTLY four spaces (no more no less). So I would confirm that your IDE is set accordingly and maybe try manually spacing your items out.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3 on windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @torinchien I don't know much about that editor but I would check to make sure that the Tab settings are set to 4 spaces. I think the default on most text programs is 5? A setting like that would definitely cause the error you describe

Comment: @JimBeam Look at the lower right hand corner of your editor. You should see something like Tab and Python.  Click Tab and change it to 4 spaces.   There is probably a setting somewhere to change this for all Python files.